# Ошибка Call to undefined method Attribute::model()

Tags: php, mysql, yii

Пс совсем недавно в программировании, развернул проект с гита, подключил свежий дамп, сайт работает, до каталога товаров)

БД проверил вроде записи в таблицах совпадает
В чем может быть беда?
Если зайти в каталог то такая ошибка:
Call to undefined method Attribute::model()
Вызов неопределенного метода

```
public function getTypeAttributesForSearchFromQuery(CHttpRequest $request)
{
    $attributes = Yii::app()->getCache()->get('Store::filter::attributes');

    if (false === $attributes) {

        $attributes = [];

        $models = Attribute::model()->findAll(
            ['select' => ['name', 'id', 'type']]
        );

        foreach ($models as $model) {
            $attributes[$model->name] = $model;
        }

        Yii::app()->getCache()->set('Store::filter::attributes', $attributes);
    }
```

Функция model класса Attribute extends \yupe\models\YModel

```
public static function model($className = __CLASS__)
{
    return parent::model($className);
}
```

Функция findAll

```
public function findAll($condition='',$params=array())
{
    Yii::trace(get_class($this).'.findAll()','system.db.ar.CActiveRecord');
    $criteria=$this->getCommandBuilder()->createCriteria($condition,$params);
    return $this->query($criteria,true);
}
```

Проект на Юпи

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Проблема была с версиями php для этого "wikimedia/composer-merge-plugin": "dev-master плагина в composer